# How to get importance of categorical feature after using DictVectorizer in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor to train a model.

My data set includes heterogeneous variables, both numeric and categroical variables. **Since sklearn does not support categroical variables, I use DictVectorizer to convert these categorical features before inputting into Regressor**. Here is a piece of my code:

```
# process numeric and categorical variables separately
lsNumericColumns = []
lsCategoricalColumns = []
for col in dfTrainingSet.columns:
    if (dfTrainingSet[col].dtype == np.object):
        lsCategoricalColumns.append(col)
    else:
        lsNumericColumns.append(col)

# numeric columns
dfNumVariables = dfTrainingSet.loc[:, lsNumericColumns]
dfNumVariables.fillna(0, inplace=True)
arrNumVariables = dfNumVariables.as_matrix()

# categorical columns
dfCateVariables = dfTrainingSet.loc[:,lsCategoricalColumns]
dfCateVariables.fillna('NA', inplace=True)
vectorizer =  DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
arrCateFeatures = vectorizer.fit_transform(dfCateVariables.T.to_dict().values())

# setup training set
arrX = np.concatenate((arrNumVariables,arrCateFeatures), axis=1)
arrY = dfData['Y'].values
```

Then, train the model and output the feature importance:

```
# setup regressor
params = {'n_estimators':500, 'max_depth':10, 'min_samples_split':50, \
          'min_samples_leaf':50, 'learning_rate':0.05, 'loss':'lad', \
          'subsample':1.0, 'max_features':"auto"} 
gbr = GradientBoostingRegressor(**params) 

# fit
print('start to train model ...') 
gbr.fit(arrX, arrY) 
print('finish training model.')

print(gbr.feature_importances_)
```

This will give me a list of (feature_index, feature_importance) tuples. **However, I find that this feature index is not the original feature index as one categorical column can be converted into several columns.**

I understand I can get vectorized feature name from DictVectorizer, but **how can I find out the importance of original features?**

could I just sum up all the importance of vectorized features which corresponds to same original feature to get the importance of original feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the feature importances for the one-hot features with

```
zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), gbr.feature_importances_)
```

This gives a list of (feature, importance) pairs, where features are of the form `'name=value'` for categoricals and just `name` for originally numerical features. The order of appearance in `get_feature_names` output is guaranteed to match the order in `transform` or `fit_transform` output.

To be honest, I'm not sure about the feature importances for the original categoricals; I'd try taking the mean rather than the sum.